# C# .net windows application setup not running in windows 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

hello i have created one windows application in c# .net and its working fine in windows xp, but when i try to install the setup in windows 7 or vista,the setup never runs.. should i have to write some code for it...?

please help

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what you mean by "the setup never runs". Are you saying that you double-click the setup.exe file and then nothing happens? Or an error message (if so, what error message)? Or something else?

Comment: yh when i double-click the setup.exe file and then nothing happens

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using? Are you using the built-in setup project type, or are you using a third-party installer library?

Comment: VS 2005 version 8,i built the setup using the visualstudio publish method..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your installer is an MSI, turn logging on to find out why.

```
msiexec NameOfYour.msi /l*v log.txt
```

Comment: sorry i didnt get u...the setup works fine in xp...but when i try to install in vista or 7 nothing happenss..

Comment: *exactly* :) You said - "when i try to install the setup" ... so if something is going wrong during setup, and your setup program (the .msi or .exe installer) is built to work with Microsoft Installer (MSI), then turning on MSI logging may help pinpoint your problem.

Comment: thankz for the information, i built the setup using the visual studio publish method..should there any other method to built setup.which will be compatable in all window version

Comment: Perhaps we're talking about different things. "Publish" is typically associated with asp.net web projects, it compiles and copies project output somewhere (local filesystem, http, ftp). "Setup" projects are separate from asp.net web projects, and create an installer (.msi) based on web project.  I'm not sure whether you're publishing an asp.net web site, or creating a setup installer.

Comment: thanks Si for the valuable information...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed the correct version of .net Framework on your box.

Comment: yh...it have the framework....but when i installed in a xp system having no .net it automatically try to download the framework, here in windows 7 there is no respone....